# Error ID 50,000 being returned within error process

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I notice when this error is triggered within the stored procedure it returns 50,000. Is there a way to modify this to say 50,999 so the front-end app can specifically pick the error up and not confuse it with anything else.

```
RAISERROR('Client already has an Active Visit!',16,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation of [RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> The message is returned as a server error message to the calling
>   application or to an associated `CATCH` block of a `TRY…CATCH` construct.
>   **New applications should use `THROW` instead.**

Emphasis mine. ([THROW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

I don't know what your SQL statement looks like, but, instead you can therefore do something like:

```
BEGIN TRY 
     --Your INSERT statement
     SELECT 0/0; --Causes an error
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW 50099, 'Client already has an Active Visit!',1;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the first parameter of the raiseerror function, like so:

```
--configure the error message
sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50999,  
          @severity = 16,  
          @msgtext = N'Client %s already has an Active Visit!';   
GO

-- throw error
RAISERROR (50999, -- Message id.  
       16, -- Severity,  
       1, -- State,  
       N'123456789'); -- First argument supplies the string.  
GO
```

Output will be

```
Msg 50999, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Client 123456789 already has an Active Visit!
```

If you don't specify the error number, the raiserror will be assumed to be 50000. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)...

Comment: @CetinBasoz in correct, this would raise the error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'Client already has an Active Visit!'.` The documentation specifically states *"When msg_str is specified, RAISERROR raises an error message with an error number of 50000."*

Answer (score 1):

With RAISEERROR, if you use message as the first parameter then you can't specify an error ID and it is implicitly 50000. However, you can create a custom message with parameters and pass your code there. ie:

```
RAISERROR('Client already has an Active Visit! - Specific Err.Number:[%d]',16,1, 50999)
```

Also Try\Catch is the suggested method for new applications.